# CSS Zoom to a div inside a div

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have a div inside a div

[image]

So what I want to do here is to zoom red (with overflow: hidden) to the blue div, so the blue div would get bigger inside red without it actually resized

How to achieve this with css?

Edit: To clarify, I have to make sure the zoom or attribute that would make the blue div got bigger is styled on the red div, since on real implementation, there'll be multiple blue div inside the red div.

Comment: So basically you want the blue div to act as a magnifier, correct?

Comment: sorry that i'm not sure what you mean by magnifier, but it's more like the blue div act as an anchor or zoom point of the red. but if you think magnifier is the correct expression, feel free to answer this question ^^

Comment: By magnifier I mean magnifying glass. If you are on windows you could search for magnifier app it will show you with it means basically it zooms on in the text and without any JS I don't believe this can be done.

Comment: ah yes, i think you hit the correct term

Answer (score 0):

Zoom is an *event*. This is what Javascript is for. Yes you can style the page do to what you want but you're going to have to respond to whatever event that is supposed to trigger the zoom, such as clicking in a particular area, page scroll to a particular point, a timer, etc.

To make a div element cover the entire viewport, make sure your html and body elements have zero padding and zero margin. Then you set CSS properties of the div, namely, height and width, to be 100%.

Comment: sorry if my question misleads you, but what i want is to style the element. i'm not trying to catch event with js, but just a simple styling with css

Answer (score 0):

**strong text**

```css
.one {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.two {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  zoom: 3.8;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: on your code, the zoom was on class two, that is inside class one. i need to make sure the zoom was on the class one (since there'll be multiple class two elements). how can i achieve that?